# Published database details on github

Tags: github

I made a mistake and I published on github my login details for my database.

How can I delete my commit and delete those details entirely from github?
Running `git reset --hard` will do the trick?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see "Remove sensitive data"

> Some day you or a collaborator may accidentally commit sensitive data,
>   such as a password or SSH key, into a Git repository.

https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data